# Replace variable with its string first and then do the `if` check

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am working on a custom WordPress plugin that has

```
// Callback for setting the if condition where theme should be used instead of Oxygen.
function ote_on_these_views() {

    $oxygen_theme_enabler_options = get_option( 'oxygen_theme_enabler_option_name' ); // Array of All Options

    $myifcondition = $oxygen_theme_enabler_options['enter_your_if_condition_1'];

    if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this in place, everything works fine. I am calling `ote_on_these_views()` a couple of times in rest of the code.

Now when I replace

```
if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) {
```

with

```
if ( $myifcondition ) {
```

it does not work because the if condition is checking to see if the variable is present (and it is) and hence `ote_on_these_views()` is always returning true.

The current value of `$myifcondition` is `is_page( 'contact' )` and is coming from the plugin's settings page.

[image]

So.. is there a way to replace the variable with its value first and then have the if statement check for it or any other workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using filters. If your users are developer-y enough to be declaring conditions such as `is_page()`, then they should be able to add a filter easy enough.

```
function ote_on_these_views() {
    if ( ote_on_these_views_condition() ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function ote_on_these_views_condition() {
    // Set our default condition value
    $oxygen_theme_enabler_options = get_option( 'oxygen_theme_enabler_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
    $myifcondition = boolval( $oxygen_theme_enabler_options['enter_your_if_condition_1'] );
    // Add a filter to allow users to override the condition
    return apply_filters( 'ote_on_these_views_condition', $myifcondition );
}
```

Now your users can easily change the result of the condition

```
add_filter( 'ote_on_these_views_condition', 'filter_ote_on_these_views_condition' );

function filter_ote_on_these_views_condition( $myifcondition ) {
    if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) {
        $myifcondition = true;
    } else {
        $myifcondition = false;
    }
    return $myifcondition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $myifcondition ) {
```

This should be

```
if ( call_user_func_array($myifcondition, array('contact')) ) {
```

where

```
$myifcondition = 'is_page'
```

You can split user entered text via

```
$condition_name=explode('(',$myifcondition,2) // 2 is max number of split parts
$params=rtrim(trim($condition_name[1]),')') //trim is used to remove any trailing spaces
```

then use

```
call_user_func_array($condition_name[0], array($params))
```

Comment: But then it won't be flexible. I want the plugin users to be able to enter any valid if condition like `is_woocommerce()`.

Comment: they will always enter function name?

Comment: No. It can be any string that returns true per https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags.

Ex.: `is_category( 5 ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( 5, get_query_var( 'cat' ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [eval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) function, but it's not a good practice to use it. Also you have to add `return` and `;` to inputed string.

```
if (eval('return ' . $myifcondition . ';')) {

}
```

As you said, you want allow only particular functions, so you can validate your expression with following regex:

```
preg_match_all("/\(?(\w+)?\(.*?\)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I'm not very good at regexps so I'm sure that it's possible to make this function much better.

For following expression:

```
is_page() && (some_function('arg') || what_else())
```

You'll get the following `$output_array`:

```
array(2
    0   =>  array(3
        0   =>  is_page()
        1   =>  (some_function('arg')
        2   =>  what_else()
    )
    1   =>  array(3
        0   =>  is_page
        1   =>  some_function
        2   =>  what_else
    )
)
```

Now you can take every used function name from `$output_array[1]` one by one and check if user can call this function:

```
if (in_array($used_function, $allowed_functions_array))
```

Comment: Ty but I don’t want to use as it is a potential security risk esp. now that user input is involved.

Comment: @SridharKatakam If you allows user input code into your app and you want to execute it or you even want to allow call any function with custom argument it's potential risk anyway. For example, then user can input `eval(...)` and do whatever he wants. If you don't want to do it, you have to think about more complicated, but more secure interface and logic of work or at least validate this expression somehow.

Comment: ok.. when I use `if (eval($myifcondition)) {`, it says



Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /Users/sridharkatakam/Sites/general/oxygen/wp-content/plugins/oxygenthemeenabler/plugin.php(38) : eval()'d code on line 1

on the frontend.

Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/raw/N02Nh7bM.

Comment: @SridharKatakam I've upated my answer. Now it should work. At least such example: `if (eval('return "asd"? true : false')) die('asd');` works properly.